# Naming Many Ranges of Variable Length

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, named-ranges

I've got a long list of values in a column that I want to make named ranges:

- **A1010 STANDARD FOUNDATIONS**
- A101001 WALL FOUNDATIONS
- A101001 COLUMN FOUNDATIONS & PILE CAPS
- **A1020 SPECIAL FOUNDATIONS**
- A102001 PILE FOUNDATIONS

Where the names of each range should be the bolded cells.

This is what I've got so far, I'm sure it's clunky but it's mine (sort of); I've cobbled it together from other bits and pieces of code I've found in other questions. It's supposed to name a range with the bold text minus the spaces; then repeatedly delete the named range and add it again with each new non-bold string.

When I try to run it, I get the error: Runtime error 9; subscript out of range.

I think I'm hung on the "RefersToR1C1" thing, which I googled but it didn't make sense to me.

```
Sub Change_Name()

Dim RngName As String
Dim MyADD As String

Sheets("Sheet 4").Select
Range("C2").Select

 While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

If ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True Then

ActiveCell.Replace " ", ""
RngName = ActiveCell.Value

Else

MyADD = ActiveWorkbook.Names(RngName).RefersToR1C1
MyADD = MyADD & "," & CStr(ActiveCell)
ActiveWorkbook.Names("RngName").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="RngName", RefersToR1C1:=MyADD

End If

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Wend

End Sub
```

I feel like I'm close, which is what I thought several hours ago. Any help is appreciated. I only know enough vba to break things and waste my time, so assume I know nothing.

Comment: is your sheet named `Sheet 4` or `Sheet4` ?

Comment: It's actually Sheet4. Now I get the error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: What, exactly, is the range on the worksheet to which you want the name to refer to?  Or is it an array and not a range?

Comment: It's a range. The ranges are different sizes, but they're separated by the range names which are bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to make a ton of replacements in names so they could be proper range names. The Range names are bold and the values are not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Change_Name()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As String
Dim RngName As String
Dim MyADD As Range
Set MyADD = Nothing
Sheets("Sheet6").Select
Range("F1").Activate

Set Rng = Nothing

 While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

If ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True Then

ActiveCell.Replace " ", ""
ActiveCell.Replace "&", "_"
ActiveCell.Replace "/", "."
ActiveCell.Replace "-", ""
ActiveCell.Replace "(", "_"
ActiveCell.Replace ")", "_"
ActiveCell.Replace ",", "_"
RngName = ActiveCell.Value
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

    While ActiveCell.Font.Bold = False And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = False

        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = Range(ActiveCell.Address)
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
            Set MyADD = Range(ActiveCell.Address)
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, MyADD)
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Wend

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RngName, RefersTo:=Rng
    Set Rng = Nothing

End If
  Wend

End Sub
```